# Can't add/edit programs to launcher

Tags: release-loki

Trying to edit a program to have a command specified before launching the program.

Adding it using MenuLibre doesn't work, manually doing it doesn't work, have tried rebooting several times.

Any edit to the main .desktop file (/usr/share/applications/obs.desktop) removes the program from the launcher (until I purge/reinstall as far as I can tell).

Edit: It seems as if it only doesn't like me adding the command before the program at the "exec" line. Works fine otherwise.

Edit2: Workaround: Have it execute a bash script with the command.

> [Desktop Entry]
>
> Version=1.0
>
> Name=OBS
>
> GenericName=Streaming/Recording Software
>
> Comment=Free and Open Source Streaming/Recording Software
>
> Comment[ru]=Бесплатная программа с открытым кодом для записи/трансляции видео
>
> Exec=LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 obs
>
> Icon=obs
>
> Terminal=false
>
> Type=Application
>
> Categories=AudioVideo;Recorder;
>
> StartupNotify=true

Comment: suggestion ... try to set up something for xclock (or Calculator)  to see if there are any errors thrown ... this might point you to any issues you are having to set this up

Answer (score 0):

maybe you're having some problem with string interpolations. May you post the command you're trying to execute? If the command in Exec= is incorrect the launcher will not load the infos in myApp.desktop

One tip for testing if the command is actually working is using xlogo before anything else. The xlogo command opens a random window so we can have a graphical confirmation that it is indeed working.

ex. `Exec=xlogo`

There are two apps that may be helpful with this and similar tasks.

**App Editor**
Edit application entries shown in application launcher menu and their properties.
http://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.donadigo.appeditor/

**Alias**
Simplify your commands: For example, you can create and organize a bunch of commands like the one that you're using now and just call it **obs-config** and then you would use like this:
`Exec=obsconfig obs`
http://appcenter.elementary.io/com.github.bartzaalberg.alias/

Comment: The command I was trying to run was included in a recent edit. (LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 obs)

xlogo doesn't appear to be working, adding a command after it does nothing. I'll look into using alias though.

Answer (score 0):

Change Exec=LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 obs

to **Exec=sh -c "LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 obs"**